# ¿Cómo relacionar dos campos con diferentes nombres a una misma tabla en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una tabla result con los campos winner y loser que deben estar relacionados con la tabla user de tal forma que pueda mostrar los usuarios cuando obtenga los registros de la tabla result, ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

```
    #user model
    class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user #que debo colocar aqui?
    end

    #result model
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :result #que debo colocar aqui?
    end

    #result index (view)
    <%= result.user.winner %> #para que algo asi sea posible?

    #result index (controller)
    @results = Result.includes(:user).all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes usar el nombre que quieras en la relación y referenciar al modelo principal con el atributo class_name:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :winner, class_name: 'User' # necesitas un campo winner_id en la tabla user
  belongs_to :loser, class_name: 'User' # necesitas un campo loser_id en la tabla user
end
```

Luego en la vista puedes hacer algo como:

```
 <%= result.winner %>
```

ó

```
<%= result.loser %>
```